# Custom field value not displaying at checkout in Simplecart

Tags: jquery, simplecart

I am not able to get 2 custom attributes to display on checkout in simplecart for size or color.  I am able to generate the headers for each column, but no data is displayed in my two custom attributes.  Everything else is in the correct spot and works across my entire website, but no matter what I do I cannot get the Size or Color attributes to display in my table.

html:

```
<h2 class="item_name">Peace on Earth T-Shirt</h2>
                <img src="../images/products/decals/poep.png">
             <span class="item_price"><h3>$17.99</h3></span>
             <select class="item_size">
                <option value="Small"> Small </option>
                <option value="Medium"> Medium </option>
                <option value="Large"> Large </option>
             </select>                   
             <input type="text" value="1" maxlength="2" size="2" class="item_Quantity">
             <br>
             <p><a class="item_add" href="javascript:;">Add to Cart!</a></p>
             </div>
           </div>
           <div class="content-three-last" id="footer-right">
           <div class="simpleCart_shelfItem">
           <h2 class="item_name">Find Him Window Decal</h2>
                <img src="../images/products/decals/fhw.png">
           <span class="item_price"><h3>$3.99</h3></span>
           <select class="item_color">
                <option value="White"> White </option>
                <option value="Pink"> Pink </option>
           </select>
```

jquery:

```
cartStyle               : "div",
                cartColumns         : [
                    { attr: "name", label: "Name" },
                    { attr: "size", label: "Size" },
                    { attr: "color", label: "Color" },
                    { attr: "price", label: "Price", view: 'currency' },
                    { view: "decrement", label: false },
                    { attr: "quantity", label: "Qty" },
                    { view: "increment", label: false },
                    { attr: "total", label: "SubTotal", view: 'currency' },
                    { view: "remove", text: "Remove", label: false }
                ],
```

result:

Shopping Cart

Name    Size    Color   Price       Qty     SubTotal

Find Him Window Decal           $3.99   -   1   +   $3.99 Remove

Peace on Earth T-Shirt          $17.99  -   1   +   $17.99  Remove

Total
$21.98

I'm not able to post a picture of the result but when I highlight over the table there is no information selected in any of these 2 columns, so any help would be appreciated!